# Should the index passed to notifyItemChanged consider placeholder items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3, kotlin-android

`PagingDataAdapter` from Paging3 library internally manages two semantically different lists. `adapter.snapshot()` returns a `ItemSnapshotList` which includes placeholder elements. `adapter.snapshot().items` return a `List` which excludes placeholder items.

Now I had to update an element using it's id. Should find and pass the index based on `ItemSnapshotList` or `List`? Eg:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(
    adapter.snapshot().indexOfFirst { it!!.id == id } // is this correct ?
    adapter.snapshot().items.indexOfFirst { it.id == id } // or is this ?
    , PAYLOAD_STATUS to Status.Active  // payloads
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. Any change on your item,you need to destroy and rebuild the pagingList.

I think the best practice is change in your room, and the list observe the room.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't include in the question. But I just wanted to change part of the view by using `Payload`s.

Comment: Check now, that I edited the question.